# Error 403 when trying to download file from website using urlib

Tags: python, urllib, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to download these 2 files from that link but it keeps returning a 403 forbidden error, the website doesn't mention requiring any authentication to access files.

```
files = [
    'sm/sm.data.1.AllData',
    'ce/ce.data.0.AllCESSeries',
]

dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
datadir = dir + "\\data"
os.chdir(datadir)

data_hostname = "http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/"
current_filesystem = datadir

def download_data():
    for filename in files: # Loop through the files in files dictonary
        filename_extension = filename[3:] + ".txt" # Filename munge
        data_location = data_hostname + "" + filename # file name location
        full_filepath = current_filesystem + "/" + filename_extension # full location
        print("downloading from: " + data_location)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(data_location, full_filepath) # grab that shit
        print("download path: " + full_filepath)
        urllib.request.urlcleanup()
    print("Finished Downloading Data")
```

Comment: A 403 means that the website made the decision not to allow you. In this case its a CDN that seems to filter based on user agent. Read the body of the response for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is missing a couple of required HTTP headers. Specifically, User-Agent and Accept-Language

Using *requests* (which you'll need to install if you don't already have it) you could do this:

```
import requests
from pathlib import Path

HEADERS = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 14_3_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.2 Safari/605.1.15",
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7"
}

CHUNK = 64 * 1024

data_hostname = "http://download.bls.gov/pub/time.series/"

files = [
    'sm/sm.data.1.AllData',
    'ce/ce.data.0.AllCESSeries',
]

(target_dir := Path(__file__).parent / "data").mkdir(exist_ok=True)

for url in (data_hostname + file for file in files):
    with requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, stream=True) as response:
        response.raise_for_status()
        target_file = target_dir / (url.split("/")[-1] + ".txt")
        with open(target_file, "wb") as output:
            for chunk in response.iter_content(CHUNK):
                output.write(chunk)
```